# How to use collection in Java

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I want to use Java collection to find the words in the list that begin with the startup letter:
example:

```
  TreeMap<String, Double> tm = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
      // Put elements to the map
      tm.put("Zara", new Double(3434.34));
      tm.put("Mahnaz", new Double(123.22));
      tm.put("Ayan", new Double(1378.00));
      tm.put("Daisy", new Double(99.22));
      tm.put("Qadir", new Double(-19.08));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+tm.get("Zar"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

in this case it will show null. But what i want to do is to show all the words that start with that letter. How can i do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: tm.get("Zar") is totally different from tm.get("Zara");

Comment: So, how can i do to get the key from it only with the starup letter?
Are there any more collection available with this feature?

Answer (score 2):

Since `TreeMap` is a [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), it is computationally cheap to iterate the map starting from a given key:

```
String prefix = "Zar";
for (String person::tm.tailMap(prefix).keySet()) {
  if (person.startsWith(prefix)) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few choices:

1. If you always go from the first three characters then do a multimap - `Map<String, List<Data>>` Where `Data` contains `String name` and `double double` and the key is the first three letters of all the names.
2. You can scan through the `TreeMap` and because it is sorted at least you know you can stop once you get past Zar - but this will still be inefficient.
3. You can use a database (embed a Derby Database for example) and use the indexing/search/query functionality of the database.
4. You can build your own tree structure branching on each character in the word. Then root->z->a->r would then give you every word beginning with zar. root->b->o would give you every word beginning with bo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to Iterate over the list and check if the key starts with the given String.

Example:

```
      for (String elem : tm.keySet()) {
          if(elem.startsWith("Zar")) {
              System.out.println(elem);
          }
      }
```

output:

```
Zara
```

and if you want to ignore the case:

```
if(elem.toLowerCase().startsWith("zar".toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeMap<String, Double> tm = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
//...add values.
//get all keys
Set<String> keys = tm.keySet();
Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
for(String key : keys){
  //check the beginning of the keys
  if(key.startsWith("Zar"){
    result.put(key);
  }
}
//get the values for your collected keys
for(String key : result){
  double value = tm.get(key);
}
```

Comment: If i have over 20,0000 entries from database and add it to tm.
with this kind of use, does it runs fast and smoothly?
Because i test with for() and Arraylist=> it seems run slow in everytime i search the word

Comment: In this case I would search after sorting the keySet and check if you can cancel the search. Also for Performance Questions: Always test it in the real setting. If there is no Problem with your current solution you do not need to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Just reading when to use what collection will only help you if you run across the exact same situation in your code. If you don't understand the roots of why a given data structure is good for a problem, you won't be able to apply this to your own code.

[this](http://javamex.com/tutorials/collections/how_to_choose.shtml) link may help you

Answer (score 0):

So How can you achieve this?

First find all the keys of HashMap by

```
tm.keySet()
```

then use iterator on keys and match with the string.See example below

```
String abc = "Zar";
HashMap s = new HashMap();
s.put("Zara", new Double(1.0));
Set x =s.keySet();
Iterator iter = x.iterator();
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
          String key = iter.next().toString();
    if(key.startsWith(abc)){
        System.out.println(s.get(key));
    }
      }
```